# IE11 Anchor Focus Dotted Outline

Tags: html, css, focus, anchor, internet-explorer-11

How are we removing the a:focus outline for IE11 ?

So far , we have lots in our base css:

```
*, *:active, button, button:active, a, a:hover, a:active,
a:focus,*:focus, a:active, 
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
select::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="file"] > input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {
    outline : 0;
    outline-style:none ;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

But for IE 11, nada - outline is always there .

From my travels I have found :

```
noFocusLine: expression(this.onFocus=this.blur());
```

but ... I would rather not !

What would be the CSS ?

Seen a few attempts to answer this on SO but no avail. Many Thanks!

Comment: I'm using outline:none; on all a elements, instead of outline 0 and it works in IE11

Comment: Thanks Omer Bonfil, actually had a declaration in the CSS ( from inherited code ) that was explicitly adding the dotted line ! : S Removed that now The outline:none, sorted it too.  Thanks

Comment: @OmerBonfil, if you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept

Answer (score 1):

using outline:none instead of outline:0 works for me.

```
a{
  outline:none;
}
```

Comment: `outline: 0` works just as well. The problem was elsewhere, as the OP says in a comment (yet mystically accepted this answer).

Comment: Quite right, @JukkaK.Korpela. I should learn how to use SO! Sorry Omer , my Bad, delete this if you want and I will get rid of this whole thread

Answer (score 0):

Add following style in css file:

```
a:focus
{
  border:0;
}
```